# CodeBlocks 12.11 on-typing annoying tip

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I've just changed from Codeblocks 10.05 to 12.11, and I noticed a really annoying 'new feature'. When type a function from C library or STL, an annoying 'method signature' appears above the text you're typing, like a tooltip or something, do someone know how to remove this 'feature'.

The 'tooltip text' hides when I click on print-screen, so it's not possible to paste a screenshot here.

Comment: It is probably handled by SmartSense, which can be disabled in Setting > Editor > Code Completion. However, it may also disable some other things you would have wanted to keep.

Comment: I've tried it, unfortunately it's not SmartSense

Comment: It still disappears when code completion is disabled, but it does not seem subtle enough. Did you ask on Code::Blocks forum? Honestly, you will probably have more accurate answers than on SO.

Comment: That's what I'm going to do. Meantime, I'll keep using 10.05 version

Comment: Well, 10.05 is already a pretty decent C++ IDE anyway :)